# I generated a disparity map using OpenCV's Stereo Vision, but all I see is a black screen

Tags: android, kotlin, opencv, stereo-3d, disparity-mapping

[android screen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heCQq.jpg)

The top left is the left camera, the top right is the right camera, the bottom left is the left camera converted to gray, and the bottom right is the disparity view.

[The Python Code I referred to](https://github.com/LearnTechWithUs/Stereo-Vision/blob/master/Main_Stereo_Vision_Prog.py)

Android Kotlin Activity Code

```
class ObjectDistanceActivity : BaseActivity(), CameraDialogParent {

        private lateinit var viewBinding: ActivityObjectDistanceBinding
    
    
         // for accessing USB and USB camera
         private lateinit var usbMonitor: USBMonitor
    
         private lateinit var handlerL: UVCCameraHandler
         private lateinit var handlerR: UVCCameraHandler
    
         private lateinit var cameraViewLeft: CameraViewInterface
         private lateinit var cameraViewRight: CameraViewInterface
    
         private lateinit var previewLeft: Surface
         private lateinit var previewRight: Surface
    
    
    
         private lateinit var distanceAnalyzer: DistanceAnalyzer
    
    
    
    
    
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    
        viewBinding = ActivityObjectDistanceBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(viewBinding.root)
    
        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            Log.d(AppUtil.DEBUG_TAG, "OpenCV Error")
        } else {
            Log.d(AppUtil.DEBUG_TAG, "OpenCV Success")
    
        }
    
    
        distanceAnalyzer = DistanceAnalyzer(this)
        distanceAnalyzer.resultListener = object : DistanceAnalyzer.OnResultListener {
            override fun onResult(leftBitmap: Bitmap, rightBitmap: Bitmap) {
                runOnUiThread {
                    viewBinding.disparityMap.setImageBitmap(leftBitmap)
                    viewBinding.objectDetect.setImageBitmap(rightBitmap)
                }
            }
        }
    
        cameraViewLeft = viewBinding.cameraViewLeft
        cameraViewLeft.aspectRatio = (AppUtil.DEFAULT_WIDTH /     AppUtil.DEFAULT_HEIGHT.toFloat()).toDouble()
        (cameraViewLeft as UVCCameraTextureView).setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener)
    
        handlerL = UVCCameraHandler.createHandler(this, cameraViewLeft, 2,
            AppUtil.DEFAULT_WIDTH, AppUtil.DEFAULT_HEIGHT, UVCCamera.PIXEL_FORMAT_RGB565)
    
           // handlerL = UVCCameraHandler.createHandler(this, cameraViewLeft,      UVCCamera.DEFAULT_PREVIEW_WIDTH, UVCCamera.DEFAULT_PREVIEW_HEIGHT, BANDWIDTH_FACTORS[0])
    
        cameraViewRight = viewBinding.cameraViewRight
        cameraViewRight.aspectRatio = (AppUtil.DEFAULT_WIDTH /      AppUtil.DEFAULT_HEIGHT.toFloat()).toDouble()
        (cameraViewRight as UVCCameraTextureView).setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener)
    
          // handlerR = UVCCameraHandler.createHandler(this, cameraViewRight,      UVCCamera.DEFAULT_PREVIEW_WIDTH, UVCCamera.DEFAULT_PREVIEW_HEIGHT, BANDWIDTH_FACTORS[1])
        handlerR = UVCCameraHandler.createHandler(this, cameraViewRight, 2,
            AppUtil.DEFAULT_WIDTH, AppUtil.DEFAULT_HEIGHT, UVCCamera.PIXEL_FORMAT_RGB565)
    
    
        usbMonitor = USBMonitor(this, mOnDeviceConnectListener)
    
        Log.d(AppUtil.DEBUG_TAG, "oncreate")
    
    
    
    
        }
    
        override fun onStart() {
         super.onStart()
        usbMonitor.register()
        cameraViewRight.onResume()
        cameraViewLeft.onResume()
    
        }
    
        override fun onStop() {
        handlerR.close()
        cameraViewRight.onPause()
    
        handlerL.close()
        cameraViewLeft.onPause()
    
        usbMonitor.unregister()
    
        super.onStop()
        }
    
        override fun onDestroy() {
        usbMonitor.destroy()
        distanceAnalyzer.flag = false
        super.onDestroy()
        }
    
         private val mOnClickListener = OnClickListener { view ->
        when (view.id) {
            R.id.camera_view_left -> if (!handlerL.isOpened) {
                CameraDialog.showDialog(this@ObjectDistanceActivity)
            } else {
                handlerL.close()
                setCameraButton()
            }
    
    
            R.id.camera_view_right -> if (!handlerR.isOpened) {
                CameraDialog.showDialog(this@ObjectDistanceActivity)
            } else {
                handlerR.close()
                setCameraButton()
            }
    
        }
        }
        private val mOnDeviceConnectListener: OnDeviceConnectListener = object :      OnDeviceConnectListener {
        override fun onAttach(device: UsbDevice) {
            if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "onAttach:$device")
            Toast.makeText(this@ObjectDistanceActivity, "USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED",      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    
            override fun onConnect(device: UsbDevice, ctrlBlock: USBMonitor.UsbControlBlock, createNew: Boolean) {
            if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "onConnect:$device")
            if (!handlerL.isOpened) {
                handlerL.open(ctrlBlock)
                val st = cameraViewLeft.surfaceTexture
                handlerL.setPreviewCallback(distanceAnalyzer.iFrameLeftCallback)
    
                handlerL.startPreview(Surface(st))
    
    
    
            } else if (!handlerR.isOpened) {
                handlerR.open(ctrlBlock)
                val st = cameraViewRight.surfaceTexture
                handlerR.setPreviewCallback(distanceAnalyzer.iFrameRightCallback)
    
                handlerR.startPreview(Surface(st))
    
            }
        }
    
        override fun onDisconnect(device: UsbDevice, ctrlBlock: USBMonitor.UsbControlBlock) {
            if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "onDisconnect:$device")
            if (!handlerL.isEqual(device)) {
                queueEvent({
                    handlerL.close()
                    previewLeft.release()
                    setCameraButton()
    
                }, 0)
            } else if (!handlerR.isEqual(device)) {
                queueEvent({
                    handlerR.close()
                    previewRight.release()
                    setCameraButton()
                }, 0)
            }
        }
    
        override fun onDettach(device: UsbDevice) {
            if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "onDettach:$device")
            Toast.makeText(this@ObjectDistanceActivity, "USB_DEVICE_DETACHED",     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    
        override fun onCancel(device: UsbDevice) {
            if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "onCancel:")
        }
        }
    
        /**
        * to access from CameraDialog
         * @return
         */
        override fun getUSBMonitor(): USBMonitor {
        return usbMonitor
        }
    
        override fun onDialogResult(canceled: Boolean) {
        if (canceled) {
            runOnUiThread(Runnable { setCameraButton() }, 0)
        }
        }
    
        private fun setCameraButton() {
    
        }
    
        companion object {
        private const val DEBUG = false // FIXME set false when production
        private const val TAG = "MainActivity"
        private val BANDWIDTH_FACTORS = floatArrayOf(0.5f, 0.5f)
    
        }}
    
     `

Android Kotlin Code
\`

    class DistanceAnalyzer(val context: Context) {
    private val lock = Any()
    private var initFinished = false
    
    private var lbpCascadeClassifier: CascadeClassifier? = null
    
    private var leftByteBuffer: ByteBuffer? = null
    private var rightByteBuffer: ByteBuffer? = null
    
    var flag = true
    
    
    val iFrameLeftCallback = IFrameCallback {
        synchronized(lock) {
            leftByteBuffer = it.duplicate()
            if (leftByteBuffer != null && rightByteBuffer != null && initFinished) {
                analyze(leftByteBuffer!!.duplicate(), rightByteBuffer!!.duplicate())
            }
        }
    
    }
    
    val iFrameRightCallback = IFrameCallback {
        synchronized(lock) {
            rightByteBuffer = it.duplicate()
        }
    }
    
    
        interface OnResultListener {
        fun onResult(leftBitmap: Bitmap, rightBitmap: Bitmap)
    }
    
    interface OnCalibrateFinished {
        fun onSuccess()
    }
    
    private val onHaarCascadeInit = object : OnCalibrateFinished {
        override fun onSuccess() {
            initFinished = true
        }
    }
    
    var resultListener: OnResultListener? = null
    
    init {
        val inputStream = context.resources.openRawResource(org.opencv.R.raw.lbpcascade_frontalface)
        val file = File(context.getDir(
            "cascade", BaseActivity.MODE_PRIVATE
        ),
            "lbpcascade_frontalface.xml")
        val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
        // asd
        val data = ByteArray(4096)
        var readBytes: Int
    
        while (inputStream.read(data).also { readBytes = it } != -1) {
            fileOutputStream.write(data, 0, readBytes)
        }
    
        lbpCascadeClassifier = CascadeClassifier(file.absolutePath)
    
        inputStream.close()
        fileOutputStream.close()
        file.delete()
    
        onHaarCascadeInit.onSuccess()
    }
    
    
    private fun analyze(leftBuffer: ByteBuffer, rightBuffer: ByteBuffer) {
        synchronized(lock) {
            val srcLeftBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                AppUtil.DEFAULT_WIDTH,
                AppUtil.DEFAULT_HEIGHT,
                Bitmap.Config.RGB_565
            )
            srcLeftBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(leftBuffer)
    
            val srcRightBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                AppUtil.DEFAULT_WIDTH,
                AppUtil.DEFAULT_HEIGHT,
                Bitmap.Config.RGB_565
            )
            srcRightBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(rightBuffer)
    
            val rgbLeftMat = Mat(AppUtil.DEFAULT_WIDTH, AppUtil.DEFAULT_HEIGHT, CvType.CV_8UC3)
            val rgbRightMat = Mat(AppUtil.DEFAULT_WIDTH, AppUtil.DEFAULT_HEIGHT, CvType.CV_8UC3)
    
            Utils.bitmapToMat(srcLeftBitmap, rgbLeftMat)
            Utils.bitmapToMat(srcRightBitmap, rgbRightMat)
    
    
            // gray convert
            val grayLeftMat = Mat()
            Imgproc.cvtColor(rgbLeftMat, grayLeftMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
            val grayRightMat = Mat()
            Imgproc.cvtColor(rgbRightMat, grayRightMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    
    
            val grayLeftBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(AppUtil.DEFAULT_WIDTH, AppUtil.DEFAULT_HEIGHT,            Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            Utils.matToBitmap(grayLeftMat, grayLeftBitmap)
    
    
            // create stereo SGBM
            val minDisp = 2
            val numDisp = 130 - minDisp
            val windowSize = 3
    
            val stereo = StereoSGBM.create(minDisp,
                numDisp, windowSize, 10, 100,
                32, 5,
                8*3*windowSize.toDouble().pow(2).toInt(),
                32*3*windowSize.toDouble().pow(2).toInt()
            )
    
            // cal disparity map
            val disparityMat = Mat()
            stereo.compute(grayRightMat, grayLeftMat, disparityMat)
            Log.d(AppUtil.DEBUG_TAG, disparityMat.toString())

            val normalizedMat = Mat()
            Core.normalize(disparityMat, normalizedMat, 0.0, 256.0, Core.NORM_MINMAX)
            normalizedMat.convertTo(normalizedMat, CvType.CV_8U)

            // convert dispairty bitmap
            val disparityBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(normalizedMat.width(), normalizedMat.height(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            Utils.matToBitmap(normalizedMat, disparityBitmap)
    
    
            // output
            resultListener?.onResult(grayLeftBitmap, disparityBitmap)
    
        }
    
        }
    
        private fun faceDistance(x: Int, y: Int, dispNorm: Mat): Double {
        var average = 0.0
        for (u in -1..1) {
            for (v in -1..1) {
                val value = dispNorm.get(y + u, x + v)
                average += value.sum()
                Log.d(AppUtil.DEBUG_TAG, value.toString())
                Log.d(AppUtil.DEBUG_TAG, "$average average")
            }
        }
        average /= 9.0
    
        return -593.97 * average.pow(3) + 1506.8 * average.pow(2) - 1373.1 * average + 522.06
             }}
```

I am trying to create a stereo vision application using the libusbcamera library and OpenCV 4.8 library. I have been working based on the GitHub repository at https://github.com/LearnTechWithUs/Stereo-Vision. I have successfully executed the process in Python, excluding the calibration part, and confirmed its functionality. However, when I attempted to convert it to Kotlin for Android implementation, the generated disparity map only shows a black screen. Could I be missing something?

I tried the solutions from both [my 'Disparity map' result is black?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37060295/my-disparity-map-result-is-black) and [Depth map - stereo image in Android with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477458/depth-map-stereo-image-in-android-with-opencv), but there were no changes.

Comment: Too much code? Minimum reproducible code?  What have you done to find which function is causing the error?  What debugging have you done? You have borrowed code?  Have you tested with their images?  Why should your images work the same?